# How can I automatically separate all the CSV files under my directory?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to apply a for loop in my current directory so that I can separate my CSV files (roughly 1000) in a way that only the first 12 rows are left, separate them by ";" & finally take the sum of row 10,11 & 12.

I have tried :

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\temp")
data = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:seq_along(data)) {
   read.csv(temp[i], header= FALSE, sep=";") 
   print(i)
}
```

but that's apparently not working at all.

Comment: How is it not working? Silently? Error message? Why do you have `temp[i]` in your loop but your vector of files is in `data`? Are the paths in `data` correct?

Comment: to read all your csv into `R` you can do a `all_csv <- lapply(data, function(x) read.csv(x, header = F, sep = ";")`.

Comment: Is ";" the separator in your files?

Comment: @Spacedman:

setwd("C:\\Users\\temp")
data = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

for (i in 1:seq_along(data)) {
   read.csv(data[i], header= FALSE, sep=";") 
   print(i)
}

it should have been this way, right!

I get the following warning message:

In 1:seq_along(data) :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used

Comment: @patL:

if i then follow your approach, wouldn't i apply the read.csv before the actual function?  i mean the first thing I wanna do is to read and separate before I then apply the function

Comment: @mrbrich:

i got this one specific row in my files which is separated with ";".  for my first step I just need this particular row

Comment: @Olli, after do `list.files` as you did, you will get all `csv` files from your directory. Doing this `lapply` you will read all your `csv` into `R`, so then you can separate them and save the output. I think would be difficult to separate the files before read them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i in seq_along(data)) {
   temp <- read.csv(data[i], header= FALSE, sep=";") 
   print(temp)
}
```

Comment: Printing large objects in a loop like this is almost never useful.